# How to remove duplicate columns after dplyr join?

Tags: r, join, dplyr

Consider two dataframes, *df1* and *df2*.
df1 has columns *id*, *a*, *b*.
df2 has columns *id*, *a*, *c*.

I want to perform a left join such that the combined dataframe has columns *id*, *a*, *b*, *c*.

```
combined <- df1 %>% left_join(df2, by="id")
```

But in the combined dataframe, the columns are *id*, *a.x*, *b*, *a.y*, *c*.

I can include "a" in the join key (i.e: `left_join(df1, df2, by=c("id", "a"))`) but there are too many of columns like *a*. I want to join only by the primary key *id* and drop all the duplicated columns in df2.

Answer (score 20):

I like to do things in as few steps as possible. I think this would reduce the numbers of steps:

```
combine<-df1%>%
  left_join(df2, by="id", suffix=c("",".y")%>%
  select(-ends_with(".y"))
```

The minus sign in the select command means that you want to select everything EXCEPT those variables. If you want to delete ALL of the duplicated columns (no column a at all), you could do this:

```
combine<-df1%>%
  left_join(df2, by="id", suffix=c(".x",".y")%>%
  select(-ends_with(".x"),-ends_with(".y"))
```

Comment: This is the best solution, so it should be the accepted answer. Between, you forgot a closing parenthesis before the last pipe symbol.

Answer (score 5):

First we perform the join by *id*

```
combined <- df1 %>% left_join(df2, by="id")
```

Then we rename those with *.x* and drop those with *.y*

```
combined <- combined %>% 
  rename_at(
    vars(ends_with(".x")),
    ~str_replace(., "\\..$","")
  ) %>% 
  select_at(
    vars(-ends_with(".y"))
  )
```

Comment: You can skip the rename of the .x variables by using `left_join(df2, by = "id", suffix = c("", ".y")`

Answer (score 2):

The more generic approach would be to drop the columns before left join otherwise your combined dataset can be very large initially:

```
df1<- data.frame(id= seq(1:0), a=rnorm(1:10,0.2),b=rpois(10,0.2))
df2<- data.frame(id= seq(1:0), a=rnorm(1:10,0.2),c=rnorm(10,0.2))

varList<- names(df2)[!(names(df2) %in% names(df1))] # get non common names
varList<- c(varList,"id") # appending key parameter

combined <- df1 %>% left_join((df2 %>% select(varList)), by="id")
```

combined dataset will not have any .x or .y

Comment: combined <- df1 %>% left_join((df2 %>% select(all_of(varList)), by="id") considering: https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest way to achieve what you're trying to do

```
df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "id", suffix = c("", ".annoying_duplicate_column")) %>%
  select(-ends_with(".annoying_duplicate_column"))
```

(Combining the answer by @Ernest Han with the very helpful comment by @David T above)

Answer (score 0):

By *"there are too many of columns like a"* do you mean you want to find all the  columns which are common to both sources? In that case, why not literally use the intersection (the default behaviour)?

```r
## two data.frames, only id = 3, a = 4 matches
(df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:3, a = 2:4, b = 3:5))
#>   id a b
#> 1  1 2 3
#> 2  2 3 4
#> 3  3 4 5
(df2 <- data.frame(id = 3:2, a = 4:5, c = 1:2))
#>   id a c
#> 1  3 4 1
#> 2  2 5 2

## this produces a.x and a.y                  
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = "id")
#>   id a.x b a.y  c
#> 1  1   2 3  NA NA
#> 2  2   3 4   5  2
#> 3  3   4 5   4  1

## which columns are common?
intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
#> [1] "id" "a"

## this produces id, a, b, c
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = intersect(names(df1), names(df2)))
#>   id a b  c
#> 1  1 2 3 NA
#> 2  2 3 4 NA
#> 3  3 4 5  1

## this is, however, the default behaviour for left_join
## i.e. use all columns which are present in both
dplyr::left_join(df1, df2)
#> Joining, by = c("id", "a")
#>   id a b  c
#> 1  1 2 3 NA
#> 2  2 3 4 NA
#> 3  3 4 5  1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: The poster doesn't want to add at the common variable level, he just wants "id" as key for left join.

Answer (score 0):

A simply solution could be:

```
df <- dplyr::inner_join(
   df1,
   dplyr::select(df2, -any_of(names(df1)), id),
   by = "id"
)
```

- names(df1) will create a vector of all the df1 names.
- any_of() is a tidyselect helper that will select any columns that are contained in df2. (See https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/all_of.html).
- The "-" before any_of() means remove that column(s).

  In other words, it will remove the columns that are already present in df2.
- Add the primary key after the any_of() to keep the "id" variable in df2.